# Limit `ssh -R` to a single port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I understand that the `permitopen="host:port"` option limits the use of `ssh -L` to a single remote port. Is there a way to do the same with `ssh -R`?

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to do the same with `ssh -R`?

Not really "the same". For the most common usage of `ssh -R` there is little to no point in having such option, but read this answer to the end.

---

#### Analysis

`PermitOpen` is an [option in `sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitOpen). It affects not only `ssh -L`, but also `ssh -D`, `ssh -W` and `ssh -J` (at least). I think it's designed as a filter to TCP connections initiated by the SSH server on request of a client.

Imagine you're an admin of the server. The client, for whom SSH may be the only entrance to the system, may be totally untrusted. The system may be a bastion the client should use only to obtain a tunnel to well-defined location(s). You are able to set things up, so the client cannot run arbitrary commands. Then you may want *your* computer not to initiate connections to random addresses for this client. `PermitOpen` lets you configure this easily.

An option in `sshd_config` that would limit the target of client's `ssh -R` is not useful for you (the admin of the SSH server) because:

1. In case of `ssh -R`, any connection to the target `address:port` will originate from the client's system which is not your concern. Your concern is the interface and the port *your* system will listen on. There is an option to limit this: [`PermitListen`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#PermitListen).
2. I don't think `ssh` (the client's application) even reports this `address:port` to the SSH server.
3. Even if it did, a modified `ssh` (or anything using the protocol) could lie. The server has no means to tell what `ssh` does with any data on its end.
4. Even if the client's application didn't lie, the client could request `address:port` you allow and locally use `iptables`, `socat`, `/etc/hosts` or its own DNS server to connect the tunnel to another address and another port.

In short: as an admin of the server you cannot control the client's side anyway. Do not try; it's not your concern.

Maybe you meant an option to limit `ssh -R` on the client's side, in `ssh_config`. At first glance such option makes some sense; but think about it and you'll notice that:

1. It's the client who *wants* a tunnel to some `address:port`, so certainly he or she won't be interested in any limiting in `~/.ssh/config`.
2. An admin of the client's system (where the client may be a regular user) may want to impose some limitations, e.g. in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. But with `ssh` personal config and command line options take precedence, the client can override any global config. This is by design and you shouldn't fight it because…
3. If you're the admin of the client's system and you don't want the client to connect to some `address:port` then what difference does it make if they try to establish such connection using `ssh`, `nc` or anything else? You need a solution with scope broader than the config of `ssh`.

   Note there's asymmetry: on the server side, in cases where SSH is the only entrance for the client to the system, limiting in `sshd_config` makes sense. On the client's side the client is *already* in the system, `ssh` is just a program he or she can use; therefore limiting (if needed) should be more system-wide than in `ssh_config`.

---

#### `PermitRemoteOpen`

There is one scenario in which the client may be interested in limiting `address:port` his or her `ssh` can connect to. And it is with `ssh -R`; but not the `ssh -R` that mirrors `ssh -L` (and I guess this is what you had in mind), but the form of `ssh -R` that mirrors `ssh -D`.

With [`ssh -R`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#R), if you (as a client) don't specify any `address:port` to forward to, then the SSH server will become a SOCKS proxy and it will be your computer who will connect to addresses requested by people using the proxy. It's like [`ssh -D`](https://superuser.com/q/1308495/432690) but the other way around.

In case of `ssh -D`, whoever uses the proxy chooses `address:port` the SSH server shall connect to on their behalf. The admin of the server may want to limit this, `PermitOpen` is the way. In case of `ssh -R` acting as a SOCKS proxy, similarly whoever uses the proxy chooses `address:port` the SSH client application shall connect to on their behalf. As a client you may want to limit this because in general these `address:port`s are not necessarily (in practice: never) your choice, but it's your `ssh` connecting to them. You can use [`PermitRemoteOpen`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#PermitRemoteOpen) in your `~/.ssh/config`. This is the option to limit `ssh -R`, but it only works when `ssh -R` creates a SOCKS proxy on the server.

---

#### Summary

- `PermitOpen` in `sshd_config` on SSH server limits `ssh -L` (and `ssh -D`, `ssh -W`, `ssh -J`). `PermitRemoteOpen` in `ssh_config` (or `~/.ssh/config`) on a client's side limits `ssh -R`.
- Each option is governed by the person whose application will eventually initiate connections: the admin of the server (owning `sshd`) and the client (running `ssh`) respectively. Limiting `ssh -R` by the admin of the server would be futile.
- Each option works in cases where the governing person is *not* the person who chooses `address:port` for the application to connect to. For `PermitOpen` all cases are like this. For `PermitRemoteOpen` only `ssh -R` creating a SOCKS proxy on the server is like this.
- Limiting `ssh -R` of other types by the client makes no sense (the client would limit himself) and there is no option for it.