# How to set up ssh tunnel for web surfing

Tags: ssh, tunnel

i have task
Use SSH to proxy out your web surfing through your Kali host.
i set up plink.exe on windows vm and openssh server on my kali host, how tunnel connection?

Comment: [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690) may be useful to understand the general concept of SOCKS proxy with SSH. In the context of the answer your Kali is `C` and your local computer is `B`.

Comment: my windows vm ip is 10.11.15.160 my kali host 10.11.0.218.this syntaxt plink.exe -l root -pw root -R 8080:127.0.0.1:80
10.11.0.218 is correct ?

Comment: I have no experience with `plink.exe` at all. I would rather expect you want `-D`. Do you know *why* you may want `-R`? Note `to proxy out your web surfing` is vague. Should other computers connect to your Windows and use the proxy? or the Windows itself only? Your question shows no research effort. Have you read the linked answer? Are you able to tell if it applies to your needs? and what case fits your situation? (e.g. `A`=`B`).