# Using PuTTY SOCKS Proxy: Do I need to add port forwarding in my router?

Tags: networking, router, ssh, proxy, putty

I'm trying to use a SOCKS proxy to forward the traffic from my Windows machine to a Linux machine. The Linux machine is running an ssh server (on a different network) on a port I'll call `2222`. To get this to work, I had to go into my router settings and set up port forwarding for that.

Currently, I'm trying to get PuTTY's SOCKS proxy to work, but traffic isn't going through. According to the tutorials I've found online, in the Tunneling menu you're supposed to give a random port, such as `8888` for example.

Is this random port used on the client's side or is it server-side and something I would need to setup in my router's forwarding settings?

Also, is there any advantage to use PuTTY instead of starting a proxy with the ssh command directly?

Comment: `Is this random port used on the client's side or…?` – Compare [this](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690). Your PuTTY acts like `ssh` in the linked answer. So yes, SOCKS proxy opens the port on the client (PuTTY) side. Then you need to point software that talks SOCKS to this port.

Comment: Thanks, that thread cleared things up. `Then you need to point software that talks SOCKS to this port` this would be for example a web browser that is told to use `localhost` on port `8888`, right?

Comment: Right. Just make sure the browser is told to use SOCKS, not HTTP proxy.

Comment: If it doesn't work then it's possible the SSH server disallows forwarding (I'm not sure if and how clearly PuTTY would report such problem to you); or the firewall there blocks what SSH server sends in your behalf to the sites you want to visit.

Comment: I found this helpful: [How To Route Web Traffic Securely Without a VPN Using a SOCKS Tunnel](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-route-web-traffic-securely-without-a-vpn-using-a-socks-tunnel)