# SSH tunnel to access third-party HTTPS pages?

Tags: ssh, https, tunnel

Is it possible to access third-party HTTPS pages over an SSH tunnel?

---

I have to access third-party websites with tight security rules from home-office.

Due to the security rules, only access from my work-PC will be allowed. I can access the work-PC by connecting to the work network through a VPN, and then can access everything via SSH. So I can access the third-party website through a remote wget (useless for a webapp), or by running a browser throw X-forwarding – with terrible performance, making it viable, but painful, for getting work done.

Since the configuration of the VPN cannot be changed due to limitations of the product in use, I have tried to tunnel the traffic to the third party website through the work PC using

```
ssh MyUserName@MyWorkPC.MyEmployer.com -L localhost:443:ThatCompany.com:443 -N
#                                      | ||        ||                     | | |
#                                      '.''----.---''--------.------------' '.'
#                      Port forwarding -'      |             |               |
#                                              |             |               |
#   Allow access to :443 only from localhost --'             |               |
#                                                            |               |
#   localhost:443 will access ThatCompany.com:443 -----------'               |
#                             through the work PC                Don't display shell
#                                                                of work PC
```

If I then try to access `https://SubDomain.ThatCompany.com`, I will get a 404 code and a page saying

```
You have reached the webserver of ThatComapany.
The URL you used is unknown to us, so we cannot allow you in.
```

### Example: Trying to access Gmail through the tunnel.

The command would be

```
ssh MyUserName@MyWorkPC.MyEmployer.com -L localhost:443:google.com:443
```

If I then try to access `https://mail.localhost` I will get:

[image]

This demonstrates two issues:

- The connection isn't considered secure, because the host name doesn't match the certificate.
- The webserver will reject the connection; It probably suspects a man-in-the-middle attack.

Is there some way to configure the forwarding in such a manner, that the webserver won't know about it?

Comment: You have to use the correct host name when talking to web servers. Name-based virtual hosts is a thing. You could edit the `hosts` file to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a SOCKS proxy over SSH:

```
ssh MyUserName@MyWorkPC.MyEmployer.com -D 8080 -N
```

and then configure your web browser for a SOCKS proxy on 127.0.0.1:8080. You should then be able to access the site as normal in your browser.

More information on SOCKS proxies in this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1308648/1154554