# linux - How to download a journal pdf from terminal?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, pdf, wget

I want to download a pdf file which is hidden inside of [website](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.963). In my home, I can not access the pdf file but if I connect to school network, I can access the the document.

The thing I want to do is that I will connect to the school server via ssh and download the file. Any ideas?

---

Attempt 1 (on Server)

```
$ wget https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.963
--2020-08-26 14:30:23--  https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.963
Resolving journals.aps.org (journals.aps.org)... 34.237.199.134, 23.22.209.44, 52.3.158.173, ...
Connecting to journals.aps.org (journals.aps.org)|34.237.199.134|:443...
```

**Freeze**

---

Attempt 2 (on Server)

```
$ firefox https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.45.963
Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
Running without a11y support!
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified
```

---

Attempt 3 (on local)

```
$ ssh -g -f -N -D 22 ...@...
bind [::]:22: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 22
Could not request local forwarding.
```

---

Comment: To fix the attempt 3, read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690). In the context of the answer your local (home) computer is `A` and `B` (`A`=`B` case), the school server is `C` and the address you want to download from is `D`. The school server may or may not allow this method.

Comment: To fix the attempt 2, you need [`ssh -X …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12755/108618) and a local X server (which may be already there if your local OS is Linux; if your local OS is Windows then you may need to install some X server for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski.

Unfortunately, the remote server (school server), I connected via ssh, refused to connect external website. It means that I can not connect any web server from my server.

I understand it when I open firefox with my local computer display option.

```
ssh ...@...edu -CY firefox
```