# SSH tunnel not working (Firefox for Mac --> remote Debian SSHD)

Tags: ssh, firefox, ssh-tunnel, sshd, socks-proxy

Running Firefox on a Mac. Debian SSHD running on remote computer. Firefox won't connect, not sure why.

I am able to ssh into the remote system on the command line on port 44. Do I need to change anything in sshd_config?

sshd_config on remote Debian system:

[image]

local Mac Firefox network settings (sorry for Japanese):

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text ([here's why](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618)).

Comment: This answer of mine explains the general concept: [How to create a SOCKS proxy with `ssh`?](https://superuser.com/a/1308648/432690)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I feel that you are expecting firefox to connect to your Debian SSHD service directly?
If that's the case, your understanding of SSH tunnel is completely wrong.
You need to run ssh client on the client machine, to 1) connect to your server and 2) start a local socks proxy. Firefox would then connect to your local socks proxy.
See below diagram:

```
+--------------+         +---------------+         +---------------+
|  firefox on  |         |  ssh client on|         |    SSHD on    |
|  client pc   +---------+  client pc    +---------+    server     |
|              |         |               |         |               |
+--------------+         +---------------+         +---------------+
```

The command to start your ssh client would be something like

```
ssh your-user@yourserver -p 44 -D 7000
```

And then in your firefox preference, the proxy host would be `localhost` and proxy port would be `7000`

Comment: And note that the ssh client provides only SOCKS proxy, _not_ regular HTTP proxy as in OP's screenshot.

Comment: Got it working. Removed the HTTP proxy; only SOCKS. Also changed to localhost in Firefox. Also had to set up port forwarding on my router at home for the port I want to use.